# Proving f (f bool) = bool

Tags: coq

How can I in coq, prove that a function `f` that accepts a bool `true|false` and returns a bool `true|false` (shown below), when applied twice to a single bool `true|false` would always return that same value `true|false`:

```
(f:bool -> bool)
```

For example the function `f` can only do 4 things, lets call the input of the function `b`:

- Always return `true`
- Always return `false`
- Return `b` (i.e. returns true if b is true vice versa)
- Return `not b` (i.e. returns false if b is true and vice vera)

So if the function always returns true:

```
f (f bool) = f true = true
```

and if the function always return false we would get:

```
f (f bool) = f false = false
```

For the other cases lets assum the function returns `not b`

```
f (f true) = f false = true
f (f false) = f true = false
```

In both possible input cases, we we always end up with with the original input. The same holds if we assume the function returns `b`.

So how would you prove this in coq?

```
Goal forall (f:bool -> bool) (b:bool), f (f b) = f b.
```

Comment: I have realised that f (f b:bool) = b cannot be proved, as if f always returned true f (f false) == f true == true != false.

Comment: However, f (f (f b)) = f (b). Perhaps this is closer to your desired question? I don't know how to prove this in Coq though!

Comment: By the way, the property you trying to prove has a name: Idempotence. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Goal forall (f:bool -> bool) (b:bool), f (f (f b)) = f b.
Proof.
intros.
remember (f true) as ft.
remember (f false) as ff.
destruct ff ; destruct ft ; destruct b ; 
    try rewrite <- Heqft ; try rewrite <- Heqff ; 
    try rewrite <- Heqft ; try rewrite <- Heqff ; auto.
Qed.
```

Comment: What language is that written in? Maths?

Answer (score 4):

A tad shorter proof:

```
Require Import Sumbool.

Goal forall (f : bool -> bool) (b:bool), f (f (f b)) = f b.
Proof.
  destruct b;                             (* case analysis on [b] *)
    destruct (sumbool_of_bool (f true));  (* case analysis on [f true] *)
    destruct (sumbool_of_bool (f false)); (* case analysis on [f false] *)
    congruence.                           (* equational reasoning *)
Qed.
```

Comment: A slightly shorter proof based on the same idea: `intros f []; case_eq (f true); case_eq (f false); congruence.`

Answer (score 4):

In [SSReflect](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr):

```
Require Import ssreflect.

Goal forall (f:bool -> bool) (b:bool), f (f (f b)) = f b.
Proof.
move=> f.
by case et:(f true); case ef:(f false); case; rewrite ?et ?ef // !et ?ef.
Qed.
```

Comment: A bit more concise proof: `by move=> f []; case et:(f true); case ef:(f false); rewrite ?et ?ef.`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for wonderful assignment! Such a lovely theorem!

This is the proof using C-zar declarative proof style for Coq. It is a much longer than imperative ones (altrough it might be such because of my too low skill).

```
Theorem bool_cases : forall a, a = true \/ a = false.
proof.
    let a:bool.
    per cases on a.
    suppose it is false.
        thus thesis.
    suppose it is true.
        thus thesis.
    end cases.
end proof. Qed.

Goal forall (b:bool), f (f (f b)) = f b.
proof.
    let b:bool.
    per cases on b.

    suppose it is false.
        per cases of (f false = false \/ f false = true) by bool_cases.
        suppose (f false = false).
            hence (f (f (f false)) = f false).
        suppose H:(f false = true).
            per cases of (f true = false \/ f true = true) by bool_cases.
            suppose (f true = false).
                hence (f (f (f false)) = f false) by H.
            suppose (f true = true).
                hence (f (f (f false)) = f false) by H.
            end cases.
        end cases.

    suppose it is true.
        per cases of (f true = false \/ f true = true) by bool_cases.
        suppose H:(f true = false).
            per cases of (f false = false \/ f false = true) by bool_cases.
            suppose (f false = false).
                hence (f (f (f true)) = f true) by H.
            suppose (f false = true).
                hence (f (f (f true)) = f true) by H.
            end cases.
        suppose (f true = true).
            hence (f (f (f true)) = f true).
        end cases.

end cases.
end proof. Qed.
```