# Coq true = false discriminate fails, no primitive equality

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to prove the following, and I think I have the right approach to solving by enumerating all the cases for `b` and all the single argument boolean functions `f` (should be 4 functions over 2 boolean values), proving the point by exhaustively destructing everything.

```
Theorem example :
  forall (f : bool -> bool) (b : bool),
  f (f b) = b.
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct (f (f b)).
  - destruct b. 
    + reflexivity. 
    + Fail discriminate. admit. 
  - destruct b eqn:Hqebb.
    + Fail discriminate. admit. 
    + reflexivity.  
Qed.
```

However, when I try to discriminate on the 2nd and 3rd steps, on `false = true` I get the following error:

```
Ltac call to "discriminate" failed.
No primitive equality found.
```

I've used discriminate before with inductive types and it worked as expected, so I was surprised it didn't work here with boolean types. Any ideas why?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1674018/2747511) is the same question. As [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674018/proving-f-f-bool-bool#comment1547967_1674018) says, one can prove something like this: `f (f (f b)) = f b` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The `discriminate` tactic only works if your context has a hypothesis that equates terms of inductive type that start with different constructors.  When you perform the first call to `discriminate`, the context looks like this:

```
f : bool -> bool
============================
true = false
```

As you can see, the context does not contain any equality hypotheses, so `discriminate` cannot do anything. To solve this, you need to use the `eqn:` option to the `destruct` tactic, so that Coq records all the relevant facts in the context.  For example, if you call

```
destruct b eqn:H.
```

and `b` is of type `bool`, then in addition to generating two subgoals as usual, Coq will add the hypotheses `H : b = true` and `H : b = false`.

(I appreciate that you changed your question, but I just wanted to note that the theorem you put there now is not provable.  It shouldn't be too difficult to adapt this to your original question.)

Comment: Interesting, I still don't get why true = false cannot be immediately marked as impossible. By the definition of `bool: = true | false` they should be impossible to be equal. I was under the impression `discriminate` works similarly to `inversion` by looking at how constructors cannot possibly match due to the type definition.

Comment: Indeed, it is impossible for them to be equal: the job of `discriminate` is precisely to recognize when these situations arise. The problem is that (1) it requires these contradictions to appear in your context, and (2) Coq is not smart enough to know all the information that you might want to leave in your context; you need to tell it explicitly. You could also always call `destruct` with the `eqn` modifier, but this would quickly make context unreadable when working on more complex proofs.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an hypothesis `true = false` (which is impossible), you can use `discriminate` to finish the goal. In the goal you are stuck with, you are asked to *prove* `true = false`. No tactic can do that, it's an impossible task!

The particular example theorem you used is actually false:

```
Theorem not_example:
  ~ forall (f : bool -> bool) (b : bool), f (f b) = b.
Proof.  
  intros H.
  specialize (H (fun _ => true) false).
  simpl in H.
  discriminate.
Qed.
```

But in general, as Arthur said, the way to do this is is to use the eqn: option to `destruct`, to remember the relevant equations. E.g. here is a proof script that mostly proves your theorem, except for the cases where it is false:

```
Theorem example :
  forall (f : bool -> bool) (b : bool),
  f (f b) = b.
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct (f true) eqn:?; destruct (f false) eqn:?; destruct b; try congruence.
```